# Openshift External IP is pending/none

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I tried to set externalPI with below command

`oc patch svc <serviceName> -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["giving.my.ip.here"]}}'`

but getting below error

`Error from server (Forbidden): services "<myServiceName>" is forbidden: spec.externalIPs: Forbidden: externalIPs have been disabled`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Forbidden: externalIPs have been disabled` is likely due to the configuration of your OpenShift cluster that currently does not allow you to create Services with an external IP.

So you may need to contact your OpenShift Administrator to allow these.

In OpenShift 3.x, you need to specify the `networkConfi.gexternalIPNetworkCIDRs` in the `master-config.yaml` (see [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/tcp_ingress_external_ports.html)).
In OpenShift 4.x, this needs to be configured in the `Network` configuration `spec.externalIP.policy.allowedCIDRs` (see [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-externalip.html#example-policy-objects_configuring-externalip))